# What is the proper way to work with local packages using yarn in Next.js project?

Tags: next.js, package.json, packaging, yarn-v2

I work in a Nextjs project that uses custom component library. The library is developed by the team and I make changes there as well.

In order to test that changes work properly before publishing, I build and pack project, then install it locally using `yarn add <file_path>` or inserting `<file_path>` straight into `package.json`. When I do this and update dependencies running `yarn` command, the command works and I can see new dependencies installing in the terminal but often changes are not picked when I run dev server. I have to re-install `node_modules`, delete `yarn.lock` and `.next` to run server in order to have changes applied.  Sometimes I only delete the package I am trying to install locally from `node_modules` and its description from `yarn.lock`, then reinstall dependencies and succeed, and sometimes it doesn't work.

I cannot see the system behind the actions I take and **would like to know what is the best way to work with packages locally in Nextjs project with yarn as package manager** without wasting time to re-install `node_modules`.

*Additional question:* I saw there is `watch` API for yarn 1.0.2 and additional libraries that can track changes in files, could these be used to solve my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing team I work in came up with is to use `yalc`. It provides a `--sig` flag for publishing local package locally. This flag adds a hash to the package. It helps to avoid re-installing the whole `node-modules` on each update and ensures that the latest package changes are always being picked by `yarn` on install.

There is also an option to attach hash to packed file on our own to decide the issue but we decided to go with a ready solution (yalc).